# Lualatex creating a tagged PDF

Tags: luatex, pdf, tagged-pdf

I have a PDF that is untagged and generated by lualatex that I need to somehow make tagged. Tagging it automatically in Adobe Acrobat Pro causes some data loss, and I know that there's an ongoing effort by the core LaTeX team to support tagging [here](https://ctan.org/topic/tagged-pdf)
, but I'm wondering if there's any other packages out there that can deliver basic tagged pdf conversion; I don't need the auto tagging to be good, I literally just need the pdf to change type into a tagged pdf. Is there any accessibility package out there that can manage that?

Comment: Your link does not work. AFAIK currently there are only [two packages for tagging](https://ctan.org/topic/tagged-pdf).

Comment: What data is lost by Acrobat Pro? If it is metadata, then in some cases, you can manually restore it, either by the same program or a separate command-line tool. But if the lost data involves vector artwork, that might indicate a problem with the artwork, such as ambiguous self-overlapping lines, or closed curves drawn in the wrong direction. If the problem is that the tags are badly-guessed by Acrobat Pro, you can manually edit them within the program.

Comment: basically there is only tagpdf for lualatex. You can tag your document with it, but how much manual intervention that needs (and how good the result will be) depends a lot on the actual document.